# Updating the Default View via Webservices

Tags: development, wss-3.0, web-services, list-view

I am trying to find a good sample code on updating the fields that are displayed within the default view.

The current code creates a list on the fly and then adds the needed columns.

Once the list is created and the new fields added, I need a way to make sure the new fields are displayed in the default view.

The issue I am having is that after I create the list and new fields, the default view is only displaying the Title field and nothing else.

Thanks.

Comment: Configuring fields in a list does not automatically add those fields to a view.  I have not had to configure a view via the web services though, and I none of the items are jumping out at me unless it is done via caml in the list update.

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute on the Method tag called AddToView which can be used when adding fields using UpdateList newFields argument.

Answer (score 0):

The SP 2010 Web Services provides calls to work with Lists and Views. The following may be of help to you -

[Lists Class and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263617.aspx)

[Views Class and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcviews.views_members.aspx)

Code fragment from MSDN [showing Views modification and update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcviews.views.updateview.aspx).